# Trying to calculate the date between Employee's age(period), with the date they were hired(LocalDate). How can I work around the datatype mismatch?

Tags: java, methods, encapsulation, period, localdate

I'm practicing using encapsulation in java to create an Employees profile. I'm trying to include both the employees age - calculated using

```
private Period age;
private LocalDate currentDate;
private LocalDate dob;
public Period calcAge() {
    currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    age = Period.between(currentDate, dob); //dob is Date Of Birth
    return age;
}
```

, and the age at which they were hired. My first thoughts were to accomplish this with the following method:

```
public Period hiredAge() {
    return Period.between(age, hireDate);
}
```

However, I receive the error "Period cannot be converted to LocalDate"

I've tried to research both a way to perform the calculation using "age" as a LocalDate - and by inputting hireDate as a Period, both to no avail. How can I calculate the age at which the Employee was hired?

Comment: *I'm practicing using encapsulation*: OK, but then start by understanding the difference between a field and a local variable. A field is part of the state of an object. It's normal for an employee to have a date f birth. But an employee shouldn't have a currentDate. That should be a local variable. And since the age can be computed from the date of birth, and since it keeps changing, it should be a local variable, too.

Comment: nit: Do you really want to represent age as a `Period` instead of an `int` or `float`?

Comment: Why do you not simply use `ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(dob, currentDate)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you calculated `age` using `Period.between(currentDate, dob)`, you can calculate the age at which they were hired using `Period.between(dob, hireDate)`.

BTW you are getting that error because you are passing `age`, which is a `Period`, not a `LocalDate` in `Period.between(age, hireDate)`.